# MongoDB returning a null, but query works separately

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In a post function, I am trying to retrieve the nth activity of a user (since I have a dropdown that return the index number of the activity). When I run the query

```
collection.find({'local.email':req.user.local.email},
      {'local.activities':{$slice : [currActivity,1]}});
```

I receive the correct activity object in Robo3T.
But, when I call the same query in Node inside a post function, it returns an undefined.

```
app.post('/addlog',function(req,res){
var currActivity = req.body.curAct;
var score = req.body.score;
var comment = req.body.reason;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://****:****@ds044907.mlab.com:44907/intraspect',function (err, database) {
     if (err)
         throw err
     else
     {
     db = database;
     var collection = db.collection('users');
     var retrievedAct = collection.find({'local.email':req.user.local.email},
      {'local.activities':{$slice : [currActivity,1]}}).toArray().then(console.log(retrievedAct));
      if (retrievedAct.length > 0) { printjson (retrievedAct[0]); }
      console.log(currActivity);
      console.log(retrievedAct[0]);
    // console.log(req.body.newAct);
    collection.update({'local.activities.name':retrievedAct[0]},
                          {$push: {'local.activities.log' : {
                            comments: comment,
                            score: score,
                            log_time: Date.now()
                          }}})
                            .then(function(){
                                res.redirect('/homepage');
                            })
                            .catch(function() {
                                console.log('Error');
                            });
     }
 });
```

});

I checked that the currActivity variable does infact contain the integer value for the nth activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result of `collection.find().toArray()`, as specified in the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray), you have two options:

- Passing a callback to `.toArray()` like you did with `mongoose.connect()`
- Using the Promise that it returns if you don't pass a callback

Now you are doing neither of them.

Also, you are mixing callback style and Promises in your code. I recommend you unificate your code. If you are using a Node.js version bigger than 8, using async/await could be nice, it makes it simpler.

Comment: I added a callback function to .toArray() like this: `var retrievedAct = collection.find({'local.email':req.user.local.email},
          {'local.activities':{$slice : [currActivity,1]}}).toArray(function(err,act){
            if(err)
                throw err
            else{
                retrievedAct = act;
            }
          });`                                                                                                                 But retrievedAct is still undefined

Comment: If you use callback style you can not get the value like that, the rest of your code must be inside the callback (like you did in the `mongoose.connect()` callback).